# Get Proc Base Adress By Name - delphi

Tags: delphi

Задача - поиск абсолютного, статичного адреса функции в адресном пространстве чужого процесса по имени.

Например:
Процесс 1.exe содержит в себе несколько модулей dll - engine.dll, entities.dll и так далее.
Эти dll имеют внутри себя много функций например: _pNetWork , CUIEditBox::s_FocusingEditBox и так далее. Так же они имеют ординату, но мне по ординате будет не удобно.

Сейчас применяю динамичное значение, что неудобно постоянным обновлением значений.

```pascal
qpid:= GetProcessID('1.exe') ;
  //WinHandle := WindowFromProcessID(qpid);
wBase = $CBF8E8;  // _pNetwork 
BaseDW := Mem.ReadDWORD(GetModuleBase(qPID,'Engine.dll') + wBase);
```

В гугле данной информации к сожалению не нашел(